# In Azure DevOps, is there a faster way to view/download test results?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm doing test review of test results done through Azure DevOps. And I'm finding it increasingly tedious to have to download screenshots for each step just to check the quality of test evidences. Imagine having to download an average of 2-3 screenshots for each step for each test case!

Does anyone have a better way of doing this? Thanks in advance! :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> is there a faster way to view/download test results?

For this issue , I'm afraid there is no faster way in web browser. The screenshots added in the test step can only be viewed and downloaded on the test run page.

As a workaround, you can try to use [Attachments - Get Test Run Attachment Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get%20test%20run%20attachment%20zip?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api to download a test run attachment by its ID.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/attachments/{attachmentId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```